# Pressure exerted by a photon

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, pressure, radiation

According to several sources, momentum of a photon is $\dfrac{h}{\lambda}$.

While doing some reading on **radiation pressure**. I came across this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure#Radiation_pressure_in_terms_of_photons) page where it was stated that "pressure due to reflected and emitted photons is identical."

[image: radiation pressure in terms of photons]

Why is that? Shouldn't reflected photons exert twice the pressure $2 \times \left( \dfrac{h}{\lambda A} \right)$, as compared to absorbed or emitted photons $1 \times \left( \dfrac{h}{\lambda A} \right)$ using simple conservation of momentum? Am I missing something here? Is the information on wikipedia correct?

From the same page, I found this helpful diagram contradicting the statement.

[image: radiation pressure illustration]

Comment: It says the incoming photon causes the same pressure as the outgoing one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the article is stating that Classical Electrodynamics (EM waves) and Quantum Theory (photons) will both give "identical" results mathematically for the radiation pressure of either reflected or emitted light; not that the radiation pressure of reflected and emitted light is identical.